# Type class instance checking can't detect "piecewise instances"

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, type-inference, typeclass, type-families

I have a family of data types indexed by type-level integers, and I define them as instances of some type class in a "piecewise" manner, which causes problems when trying to derive instances of another class. To illustrate, I have isolated the problem as follows. Consider this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeSynonymInstances,
             FlexibleInstances  , UndecidableInstances #-}

data Zero
data Succ n

type One   = Succ Zero
type Two   = Succ One
type Three = Succ Two

class Nat n where
  toInt :: n -> Int

instance Nat Zero where
  toInt _ = 0
instance Nat One where ------------------------- START MODIFY
  toInt _ = 1
instance (Nat n) => Nat (Succ (Succ n)) where
  toInt _ = 2 + toInt (undefined :: n) --------- END MODIFY
```

This is a slight modification of the type-level integers defined in ["Fun with type functions" by Kiselyov, Jones and Shan](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/assoc-types/fun-with-type-funs/typefun.pdf). This compiles fine and `toInt` seems to work as expected. Right now `Nat` contains all integers `Zero`, `One`, `Two` and so on.

However GHC complains after I add the following lines and recompile:

```
class LikeInt n where
  likeInt :: n -> Int

instance (Nat n) => LikeInt (Succ n) where
  likeInt = toInt
```

Error: Could not deduce the `(Nat (Succ n))` arising from a use of "`toInt`" from the context `(Nat n)`.

My guess is that when GHC infers that `toInt` has an argument of type `Succ n`, but the only instances for `Nat` are for `Zero`, `Succ Zero` and `(Nat n0) => Succ (Succ n0)`, and `Succ n` matches to none of those. This guess is supported by a successful compile when I replace the `MODIFY` block with the original

```
instance (Nat n) => Nat (Succ n) where
  toInt _ = 1 + toInt (undefined :: n)
```

**How can I get `likeInt` to work just like `toInt`, even with the modified block? This is important for my actual project.**

Comment: I'd like to note here that with modern GHC features and libraries (closed type families, data kinds, singletons) we have more powerful and convenient type-level programming facilities than what's presented in the quoted paper.

Comment: Also, why can't you have the modified instances for `Nat`?

Comment: The modified instances compile, but when I try to derive instances for `LikeInt` it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just define this instance?

```
instance Nat n => LikeInt n where
  likeInt = toInt

*Main> likeInt (undefined :: Zero)
0
*Main> likeInt (undefined :: One)
1
*Main> likeInt (undefined :: Two)
2
*Main> likeInt (undefined :: Three)
3
```

Or would you like to avoid the `Nat` constraint?

Comment: I deliberately defined `LikeInt` that way to show a discrepancy between programmer logic and compiler logic. In my actual project I needed instances defined differently on different subsets of natural numbers, so in this case you could say `likeInt` is only defined this way for positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler told you what to do.

You had

```
instance (Nat n) => LikeInt (Succ n) where
  likeInt = toInt
```

And the compiler said:

> ```
> Could not deduce (Nat (Succ n)) arising from a use of ‘toInt’
> from the context (Nat n)
> ```

So we change the context to give the constraint the compiler asked for. Magic!

```
instance (Nat (Succ n)) => LikeInt (Succ n) where
  likeInt = toInt
```

(and this indeed compiles).